# cannot find apt-front on 16.04

Tags: apt, system-installation, deb

I am looking for apt-front on Ubuntu 16.04 because I get the error `fatal error: apt-front/utils/shared.h: No such file or directory`. On Ubuntu 14.04 I see:

```
# aptitude search apt-front
i   libapt-front-dev              - High-level library for managing Debian packages
```

On Ubuntu 16.04 I don't get it:

```
# aptitude search  libapt-front
#
```

My source list is:

```
# grep ^deb sources.list
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```

Am I misssing an url? What can I do on Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libapt-front doesn't exist anymore in 16.04. I think that latest version is Ubuntu 10.04.